# Operation to do when entity is saved

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I use spring boot 2, spring data-jpa with  hibernate.

I have 3 entity to check when there are saved.

If 1 is save, I need to save 2 and 3
If 2 is save, I need to save 1 and 3
...

> As stated in JPA 2 specification (JSR 317):
>
> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not
>   invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other entity
>   instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence
>   context. A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship
>   state of the entity on which it is invoked.

what should be the best way to do it?

Comment: @EntityListeners

Comment: I had a similar question, and searched over the internet but didn't find a suggestion. Finally I created a new thread to do this, but this way I can't control the transaction. Hope someone can give proper solutions